Hibernate 6.x `AbstractEntityPersister` class `hydrate` method replacement?
I'm migrating Hibernate from 5.6.10 to 6.1.7 and can't seem to find a suitable replacement for the hydrate method for intercepting the Resultset and performing a custom unmarshalling (via extending SingleTableEntityPersister which ultimately extends AbstractEntityPersister)
It's surprising that version 6.1.7 has kept the dehydrate method but not the hydrate method.
Thanks for any pointers.

dehydrate looks like deprecated and check here in 5.6 they mention to move the functionality.

public java.lang.Object[] hydrate​(java.sql.ResultSet rs, java.io.Serializable id, java.lang.Object object, Loadable rootLoadable, java.lang.String[][] suffixedPropertyColumns, boolean forceEager, boolean[] propertiesForceEager, SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws java.sql.SQLException, HibernateException


Unmarshal the fields of a persistent instance from a result set, without resolving associations or collections. Question: should this really be here, or should it be sent back to Loader?

It is removed with this commit. You may try BasicLoader implementation but this much customization will bring future problems,  I would suggest to remove hydrate dependencies totally from your code base and use hibernate as simple as possible.
